# Run ./script.sh from PHP

Tags: php, bash, shell, mpc, mpd

I have web server that play music from Raspberry and turn on LED with script gpio.sh.
I am using mpd, mpc and gpio.

My /var/www/index.php :

```
<html><body><?php
echo exec('whoami');
if(isset($_POST['button1']))
{
   shell_exec('mpc play')
   shell_exec('/bin/bash /var/www/gpio.sh');
}
?>
    <form method="post">
    <p align=center>
    OUTPUT (AUDIO) => <button name="button1">PLAY</button>
    </p>
    </form>
    </body></html>
```

In terminal, I can run /bin/bash /var/www/gpio.sh successfully and LED turning on.
From web server 'mpc play' WORKS and can play a song BUT it can't run that gpio.sh .
The owner of index.php is www-data

> -rwx------  1 www-data www-data 1262 Dec  8 10:45 gpio.sh
>
> -rwx------  1 www-data www-data  272 Dec  9 09:39 index.php

What should I do ? When I change owner of index.php or gpio.sh to root, php can't execute.
Is my index.php wrong?
I can't execute .sh from php.
Please help.

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393265/executing-sh-scripts-via-php

Comment: @marco Mura: Not Help. Still not working. :(

Comment: I think (not sure though) shell_exec waits for its command to finish (synchronous). So, in your case it might be waiting for your song to finish before executing the gpio.sh script. Either try putting '&' (background) for song or remove shell_exec('mpc play') to see that gpio.sh gets executed well!

Comment: I have try to remove mpc play in index.php. And I run mpc play in command line, then I run my index.php but still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect solution for you would be to set [SUID](http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/12/suid-set-suid-linuxunix.html) for script gpio.sh but unfortunately
[you can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18698976/suid-not-working-with-shell-script) do so as far as gpio.sh is a script.

You have three options:

- You can turn your script into the say C++ application and then set SUID
- You can use some GPIO lib for python that don't force usage by root like: [pigpio](http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html)
- You can set SUID for python interpreter, but I'm not sure its good idea generally